# Using $scope.$apply in TypeScript when using Controller as vm syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

In my current project I'm working on Angular with TypeScript. I'm using the "Controller as vm" syntax in routing, and due to that reason I'm not injecting the scope service in controller.

I'm doing some jQuery coding, after which I need to do `$scope.$apply()` to run the Angular digest cycle. Is there a way to do this without injecting the `$scope` variable into the controller?

I believe if I inject the `$scope` variable it will kill the purpose of using "Controller as vm" syntax (correct me if i'm wrong).

Comment: Do inject `$scope`. It doesn't kill the purpose of `vm`.

Comment: No, with the Controller as syntax, `$scope` is just a dependency that gets injected, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: when you need apply should inject $scope. but you can just use $scope as service and do not attach your model to it. in fact there is just one reason to inject in angular controller as fashion: when you need $scope service methods like $apply or $watch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styleguide with the vm allows you to use $scope for some purposes like initialize watchers and running diggest cycle.

Just to keep in everyones mind :) : https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

You could handle through your vm (parent-scope and such things), but it's much cleaner to use $scope directly for such usages.